# How to get variables in div loaded with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

While working with jQuery and PHP a problem occurs with loading new data from "give-me-more-results-below-the-div.php".
I have the tooltips working below with '.live', but the values of the new loaded content are not available.

Now, how would one get info from new data, loaded in a div, but (naturally) not showing in the page code? :-)

As you can see, I only need three variables to pass: main_memberID, like_section and the like_id.

I'm seriously lost here. So any help is highly appreciated.

So far, I got this on the jQuery functioning part:

```
$(".ClassToLike img[title]").live('hover', function() { 
    $('.ClassToLike img[title]').tooltip({ position: 'center left', offset: [0, -2], delay: 0 })
});

$('.like_something').live("click", function (event) {
    var value = $(this).attr ( "id" ); 

    $(this).attr({
        src: '/img/icons/checked.gif',
    }); 

    $(".tooltip").live().html('you like ' + this.name);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'like_something.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            main_memberID: $('#main_memberID').val(), 
            like_section: $('#like_section').val(),
            like_id: this.id,
        },
        success: function(){ //alert( 'You have just clicked '+event.target.id+' image');
        },  
        error: function(){
          alert('failure');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add some additional information: Did your browser request the file `like_something.php`? Did the success or the error callback execute? Is your problem requesting the information from the server, or inserting a new div? Or maybe it is requesting new data every time new information is available?

Comment: Can you post the code to `like_something.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem, first open up your browser's requests panel, in Chrome it's a "Network" tab in Dev tools. When you click `.like_something`, is a request sent? And are there any console errors? If the request is sent, look at the Response tab and see what the server is sending back.

Also, you could store the data you need to send with the request in an attribute with the [`data-` prefix](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), like this:

```
<a href="#" class="like_something" data-section="section" data-member-id="Member id">
...
</a>
```

This is most likely not your exact HTML, but you get how it works.

Then you can retreive it in the jQuery like this:

```
data: {
    main_memberID: $(this).attr('data-member-id'),
    like_section: $(this).attr('data-section'),
    like_id: this.id,
},
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Super thanks for the input you all!
Nathan gave me the best way to retrieve and pass the info I needed.

Again, this place is great. Thanks for all the efforts!

Comment: @KJS Glad it helped :) Would you mind clicking the little check mark next to my answer (under the up and down arrows)? This is [how you say that your question is answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/166675) on Stack Overflow so people will know not leave anymore answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I often id the div like

```
<div class="like_something" id="div_memberID_sectionName_anotherID"/>
```

Then

```
$('.like_something').live('click',function(){
     var info = $(this).attr('id'); // get the id
     var infoArr = info.split('_'); // split the id into an array using the underscore

     // retrieve your values
     var memberID = infoArr[1];
     var sectionName = infoArr[2];
     var id = infoArr[3];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Still getting the hang of working on this site, but this one is my closing (as posted under Nathan's answer):

Super thanks for the input you all! Nathan gave me the best way to retrieve and pass the info I needed. Again, this place is great. Thanks for all the efforts!